# Anaconda tensorflow packages incomplete? (just few kilobytes filesize)

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, anaconda

I am following the instruction at https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu to install "tensorflow-gpu" (currently 1.12.0 for linux64) by running

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu
```

in the currently active conda environment. At first this seems to work fine as in python3, I can `import tensorflow as tf`, but then I cannot even access e.g. `tf.__version__` since it is undefined.

I then found out at https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu/files that all the recent tensorflow-gpu*.tar.bz2 packages are just a *few kilobytes* in size. Similarly, all non-gpu packages at https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow/files also are just around 4kb in size. This seems odd as tensorflow should easily require *few hundreds of megabytes*. So my question is, what is the point of these few kilobytes conda packages, and what am I doing (and understanding) wrong if I want to install tensorflow in an anaconda environment.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. You can get tensorflow working by installing it using pip instead of conda using:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```